# Highcharts : Plotting Data versus Date

Tags: highcharts

I am having some data which looks like `[{"data":[22,27,22,13],"name":"Data1"},{"data":[31,31,31,50],"name":"Data2"}`. Every value corresponds to a progressing day. How do I plot this data versus date, while the length of data being dynamic.

I don't want to specify the "Categories", because my data is dynamic. Range varies everytime. I can supply the start date and end date.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/978svgc9/) here.

Comment: You can set pointInterval, like here http://jsfiddle.net/978svgc9/1/. Let me know if that is correct.

Comment: Yes, its correct. How do I set the start date dynamically? Ex. 03 April 2015

Comment: You can set that by [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart)

Comment: Yes, thank you. You could post this as an answer, so that it would help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [pointInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval) / [pointStart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart), like here.

```
plotOptions:{
        series:{
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015,4,1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/978svgc9/2/